# MySQL seems to be overwriting records

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I have a brand new table in MySQL that can be described as such:

```
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|   Team    |   Match  |  Auto | Gear | Kpa | Climb |
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|   1721    |     1    |   3   |  5   |  5  |   1   |
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|   5813    |     2    |   2   |  2   | 15  |   0   |
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
```

When I try to make a new entry into the table with the following syntax

```
INSERT INTO 2017marea (Team, `Match`, Auto, Gear, Kpa, Climb) VALUES ('1721', '19', '3', '5`, `15`, `1`);
```

and then I print the table again I can only see 1721's newest record, not their older one. I tried adding a fourth column with an auto increment primary key but it still kept the same behavior.

How do I stop it from overwriting old data while writing new data to the database?

**Edit for clarity:** Here's what the new table would look like after the insert command.

```
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|   Team    |   Match  |  Auto | Gear | Kpa | Climb |
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|   5813    |     2    |   2   |  2   | 15  |   0   |
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
|   1721    |    19    |   3   |  5   | 15  |   1   |
+-----------+----------+-------+------+-----+-------+
```

**Edit:** function used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `2017marea` (`Team` INT(25) NOT NULL, `Match` INT(25) NOT NULL, `Auto` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL, `Gear` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL, `Kpa` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL, `Climb` TINYINT(2) NOT NULL);
```

**More edits:** It's `mysql_` via the `mysqli_` shim (yes. I know. I am aware. It's never leaving a local network).

**OK. This has become a PHP problem.**

I can no longer get the issue to reproduce in the MySQL console. I have isolated the issue down to my PHP code. I'm still not sure what the issue is - `insert ignore` doesn't work either.

**More edits, oh boy.** This is a copy of my entire PHP logic. The database I provided here for an example is different (not as large of a table) as the actual, so the PHP code is slightly different. At any rate, here it is:

```
if (isset($_POST['team']) && isset($_POST['match']) && isset($_POST['auto']) && isset($_POST['gear']) && isset($_POST['kpa']) && isset($_POST['climb'])) {
    $team = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['team']);
    $match = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['match']);
    $auto = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auto']);
    $gear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gear']);
    $kpa = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['kpa']);
    $climb = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['climb']);

    $postQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 2017marea (Team, `Match`, Auto, Gear, Kpa, Climb) VALUES ($team, $match, $auto, $gear, $kpa, $climb)") or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
    if ($postQuery) {
      echo "<script> window.location.replace('../scouting/index.php?s=1')</script>";
    } else {
      echo "<script> window.location.replace('../scouting/index.php?f=1')</script>";
    }
  } else {
    // This is an HTML form. Truncated for easy display.
  }
```

Comment: Please include your full table schema.  However, `INSERT` does not work in the way you describe, so something else is going on.

Comment: Be sure you have not trigger related  to insert ..

Comment: curious why you are quoting the numbers in the insert statement when they are INTs in the table schema?

Comment: @FrankRalphBob it seems to be working just fine? Sorry for formatting this code was copied out of a PHP script.

Comment: `INSERT` always adds to the table, unless you use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause, and that requires that there be a unique index on a column.

Comment: I feel the question doesn't hold enough information since it was originally tagged as php and may hold code that could be relevant to this and a possible unknown SELECT query.

Comment: @BrennanMacaig Are you sure the PHP script doesn't check whether the team is already in the table, and do an `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT` when it finds it?

Comment: Are you doing the insert through the php or through the MySQL console?  If it is through the php, I suspect the problem lies there.  Maybe you can post your php code?  You can try the insert through the console and see if you get the same results - if not, the problem is in the php, if so, then there is something very odd happening in the MySQL database.

Comment: Lord knows that I tried to get more information. You may have left the question and trying to figure this out and wishing you well with it, really. If nobody else can solve this, then you'll have to take it up with the one given below, that's if it's still there. @BrennanMacaig

Comment: the PHP I'm using is `mysql_` via the `mysqli_` shim (yes. I know.). It's super straight forward, so I doubt it's creating any issues. I was able to replicate the issue via the MySQL console also.

Comment: @BrennanMacaig Well, if you can duplicate on the MySQL console there is something truly amiss with your schema.  You can put a unique key on the table and do an `insert ignore` - that might be a temporary work around - although you do need to fix this.  This is beyond my comprehension however.   Keep trying different stuff and post it and maybe a clue will show.

Comment: @FrankRalphBob the issue has magically stopped working in the MySQL console. It must be some issue with my PHP, but I'm not sure what. I'll investigate and keep posted. That's really weird that it was able to reproduce in the console earlier. All hope is not lost.

Comment: I have updated my problem to say that this has become a PHP problem. Any thoughts on how to resolve are appreciated.

Comment: Please post the PHP script code. And not just the one line of code you put in your new question, we need to see the whole logic.

Comment: @BrennanMacaig Your best bet is give us post entire PHP file, as the problem might not be only in statement calling the SQL.

Comment: @Barmar updated post to include logic.

Comment: I'm really confused; your new edit contains more columns than your DESCRIBE schema and you're not checking for errors as I said in your other question.

Comment: Show the actual database schema. I don't know why you think you're helping things by showing an abbreviated schema.

Comment: @Fred-ii-updated to show the full schema and now with error checking (I just hadn't typed it out yet when I posted the new code)

Comment: @BrennanMacaig Looks like we haven't found resolution here yet.  Can we try something?   Can you comment out the insert statement in the php code and then run it?  See if the database changes then.  It will help determine if the insert statement is the culprit or something else.  Currently from what you have posted, I don't see any errors.  A few rules of thumb have been broken (using reserved words for column names, starting table names with numbers), but I don't think those should be causing the problem.  After you try it out, let us know how it goes.

Comment: How do you "I print the table"?  Do you have _no_ indexes on the table?  Or did you fail to show them?