# PHP overwriting MySQL records

Tags: php, mysql

I asked a [question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42795728/mysql-seems-to-be-overwriting-records) and the problem quickly devolved into a PHP problem (as MySQL suddenly behaved again.)

The problem still stands however. I am using `mysql_` via the `mysqli_` shim (see [the github page here](https://github.com/dshafik/php7-mysql-shim)). I am fully aware of the security concerns that this poses, but am not concerned with them in this case (this project will exist on a Raspberry Pi on my local network and will be used by me, myself and I, and contains no user data).

At any rate, the issue is as follows:

I have an empty table, and give it two records. Example:

```
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   Team    |    Play   |      Notes        |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   1721    |     1     |   Nothing new.    |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
|   5813    |     2     |   Nothing old.    |
+-----------+-----------+-------------------+
```

When I update the table with an `INSERT INTO` command (or `INSERT IGNORE` for the record), it simply overwrites the row where 1721 last appeared. Here's the command that created the table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `2017marea` (`Team` INT(25) NOT NULL, `Play` INT(25) NOT NULL, `Notes` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
```

I can manually add records that won't overwrite from the console, but after doing so the PHP script simply overwrites the top record.

Here's the PHP that causes the error (the only DB access in this file).

```
$postQuery = mysql_query("INSERT INTO 2017marea (Team, Play, Notes) VALUES ($team, $play, '$notes')");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: if any of your values are strings, they need to be quoted. Those variables are unknown

Comment: None of the values in the table are in quotes. I have surrounded all my ints in quotes, the issue still remains. @Fred-ii-

Comment: yet the columns you shown from your DESCRIBE, the columns in the query doesn't match

Comment: Editing to better show my PHP code, as the `DESCRIBE` I provided was not my exact table, simply one that is capable of reproducing the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't start a new question. Edit the original question to add the clarifications.

Comment: if this is a php problem, use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and use `mysql_error()` on the query.

Comment: Is `team` actually 25 long? That exceeds `int`s. Maximum int is `4294967295` unsigned or `2147483647` signed.

Comment: @chris85 MySQL doesn't use the size of `INT` for the database datatype, it's just used for formatting output.

Comment: @Barmar It should be, I've seen it intended to be used as the number of decimal places being stored though.

Comment: @chris85 That's for `DECIMAL` types, not `INT`.